# How do you play Minecraft with someone who doesn't have it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I really want to play with a friend but he doesn't have Minecraft. Is there a way to to play with my friend who does not have Minecraft?

Comment: You could buy them a copy of Minecraft.

Comment: Unless you want to partake in illegal activities, you would have to buy him a copy, or play it on XBOX (which allows up to 4 users per console (which would all be 1 copy)).

Comment: There is nothing in this question about unreleased or illegal content.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why this was closed.  Granted, the only real answer we can support is, "Use the trial", but that itself doesn't make the question off-topic, I feel.

Comment: Looking at it now, the question itself is not off topic (but the answer the user is hoping for is more than likely to be involving illegal activities).

Answer (score 6):

You could lan play with your friend using the trial version of minecraft, but if you both like the game, purchasing full versions is recommended.